# textView onclick functionality not working programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, buttonclick

I have implemented an onclick functionality on textview, tries to open another activity view. But OnClick functionality is not working on textview.
Here is my code:

**login.xml**

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/link_signup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/signUp_text"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    // Set up the login form.
    mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
    populateAutoComplete();

    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (id == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                attemptLogin();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            attemptLogin();
        }
    });

    final TextView mSignUpButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_signup);
    mSignUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            mSignUpButton.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            attemptSignUp(view);
        }
    } );

    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
}
public void attemptSignUp(View view){

     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignupActivity.class);
     startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SIGNUP);
}
```

Please advise what is wrong in my code. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your `onClick()` method being called?

Comment: @DavidWasser No my `onClick()` method is not called as textcolor has not changed

Comment: Please post full contents of `login.xml` layout.

Answer (score 0):

Your TextView has cursorVisible attribute. cursorVisible should be used with EditText.
Try if it works after removing the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with your brackets.

It should be:

```
    ....
    final TextView mSignUpButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_signup);
    mSignUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            mSignUpButton.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            attemptSignUp(view);
        }
    } );
}
public void attemptSignUp(View view){

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignupActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SIGNUP);
}
```

That is, don't define a method inside another method, assuming that's what you have done.

If not, it means that you have referred to the `TextView` and set the `onClickListener` outside a method. Hence, it is never executed. Try moving it inside the `onCreate` method.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    final TextView mSignUpButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_signup);
    mSignUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            mSignUpButton.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            attemptSignUp(view);
        }
    } );
}
public void attemptSignUp(View view){

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignupActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SIGNUP);
}
```

Comment: I have already create the `OnClickListener` method in `OnCreate` Method

Comment: In that case, your `attemptSignUp` is probably also in `onCreate`, based on the brackets you have placed. Move it out.

Comment: In that case, please update your question with the correct code.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check and advise.

Comment: No it does not work on double click, even the click on login button is not working

Answer (score 0):

**Please check with Log within OnClickListener ,**

```
 final TextView mSignUpButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_signup);
        mSignUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Log.e("checking","within on click function");
                mSignUpButton.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                attemptSignUp(view);
            }
        } );

public void attemptSignUp(View view){

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignupActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SIGNUP);
}
```

**In case, its log print in logcat,**

its not an OnClickListener problem; its attemptSignUp() method problem.

Check it.